# Github package not found during build

Tags: android, gradle, package, publish

I added one of my own Github packages as a dependency to my Android Studio project. When I executed the Gradle sync, everything seemed fine and there were no errors. However, the next time I ran "Rebuild project" I got the the following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find <my_config_properties_reader_package>:1.0.7.
Searched in the following locations:
 - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/<my_config_properties_reader>/1.0.7/config_properties_reader_android-1.0.7.pom
 - https://jcenter.bintray.com/<my_config_properties_reader>/1.0.7/config_properties_reader_android-1.0.7.pom
Required by:
   project :app > project :identity_provider_access
```

The classes and interfaces from the package can be imported without any problems but I cannot run a successful build.
Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Is this Github Package a private repo or public repo?

Comment: It is a private repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I created a project with app and module which used another github package.
When building the app I got the same error.

Finally my project was structured as follows

```
project
   app
   module_project
      module_dependency
```

For me it helped to add the github repository of the dependency module (module_dependency) to the gradle of my app. The user credentials are retrieved from a file "github.properties" that is located directly under the project.

```
def githubProperties = new Properties()
githubProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("github.properties")))

repositories {
    maven {
        name = "GitHubPackages"
        url = uri("uri_module_dependency")
        credentials {
            username = githubProperties['gpr.usr'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER")
            password = githubProperties['gpr.key'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY")
        }
    }
}
```

the file looks as follows:

```
gpr.usr=your github account user name
gpr.key=your created github personal access token
```

Comment: Can we use the repo's **GITHUB_TOKEN** instead of hardcoding the gpr key?